# Opening boot menu when keyboard is not working

Tags: boot, bios

How do I access my boot menu.My keyboard is working just fine but during boot it seems to shutdown (so is my mouse) I want to access boot menu.

Comment: Are you pressing the esc key to get to the boot menu? Please provide as many details as you can.
here's few things you can try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @user25406 no I press f11

Comment: Hey Maahi! Here's an excerpt from [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-enter-bios-2624481): "Some PCs with both PS/2 and USB connections are configured to only allow USB input after the POST. This means that if you're using a USB keyboard, it could be impossible to access BIOS. In that case, you'd need to connect an older PS/2 keyboard to your PC to access BIOS."